# windows batch file to copy a file from a server to local

Tags: windows, ftp, batch-file

I would like to write a little code that copy on a local pc a file from another (a server).

Which Windows batch file function I can use to write this little batch file program, (FTP maybe?)

And also to visualize a message on my pc (the local pc)

thanks for all

Comment: You can only use ftp if there is a ftp server set up on that server.  Is there?  Also, what do you mean "visualize a message on my pc"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I know that if I use the FTP it works. With Visualize I mean a message pop up or something like that that appears, by mean a scheduled task, on my monitor. The FTP should connect to the server by a user flag with username and password, or by an IP address, the address of the server. I also would like to send this message to other PC, with an IP address differento than mine.

Comment: I have used the following line: "ftp user username password server" but it doesn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

It can be called from your batch file and will download from HTTP and FTP.

Comment: Before using the wget, is there some explanation on how to use it? With my request for instance.

Comment: @aemme, there's nothing to it.  `wget http://www.somedomain.com/somefile.txt`  Read the MAN page here:  http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html  There are many more options listed, but you didn't mention anything specific that you needed.

Comment: @aemme, as far as sending a message to another PC goes, the only simple way to do this in a batch file is with the Windows Messaging Service.  Then you can call `net send`(http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true).  Note that you will have to start this service manually, as it is disabled by default due to its usage by spammers some time ago.  If you are behind a firewall, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: thank you, for the wget I have to ask to my bosses...I will a.s.a.p., but if you how to do it with just FTP windows command I would appreciate it. Thank you again,

Comment: @aemme, You can make an FTP batch file.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269   Not sure why you'd want to do that though.  It is far more problematic than just using wget.

Comment: i have used the commands Ftp "ip address" and then I would like to log to the D: disk and then in the directory _BACKUP. But it doesn't work, in the sense that if I write cd D:\ it says "550 D:\: The fileanme, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: @aemme, your FTP server has no knowledge of your D: drive.  You need to configure your FTP server correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Write `SHUTDOWN -i` in a note pad then save to desktop and name it anything but it must have `.bat` at the end and then click save and u can shutdown any computer in you server.